# Load reveal modal while an ajax is running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation

Hi I am calling an ajax from my php page and while the ajax is running i would like to load a image on foundation reveal modal.

this in my code.

```
<div id="loadinimg" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
        Loading!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
</div>

   $('.print-button').click(function() {

        $.when(
        $.ajax({
                url: 'newphp1.php',
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#loadinimg').foundation('reveal', 'open');
                },
                data: {
                        selected_date: '<?php echo $GLOBALS["selected_date"] ?>'
                },
                error: function(data){
                },
                success: function(response){
                         alert(response);    
                         console.log(response);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loadinimg').foundation('reveal', 'close');
                }
         })).done(
               $.ajax({
                        url: 'newph2p.php',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                                selected_date: '<?php echo $GLOBALS["selected_date"] ?>'
                            },
                        error: function(data){
                            },
                        success: function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            console.log(response);
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }));
         });
```

but the reveal modal is getting popped up only at the end of the ajax execution. what can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `beforeSend` and `complete` option of `ajax` like one below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'newphp.php',
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loadinimg').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    },
    error: function(data){
    },
    success: function(response){
             alert(response);    
             console.log(response);
    },
    complete: function() {
             //close the loading image
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$.when(
$.ajax({
        url: 'newphp.php',
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loadinimg').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        },
        error: function(data){
        },
        success: function(response){
                 alert(response);    
                 console.log(response);
        },
        complete: function() {
                 //close the loading image
        }
 })).done(function(){
       //make another ajax call here
 });
```

**UPDATE 2**

This might be the only way left now!! Just set a global variable in js file like one below:

```
var ajax1Complete=false;

$.when(
$.ajax({
        url: 'newphp.php',
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loadinimg').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        },
        error: function(data){
        },
        success: function(response){
                 alert(response);    
                 console.log(response);
                 ajax1Complete=true;//set it on success
        },
        complete: function() {
                 //close the loading image
        }
 })).done(function(){
       if(ajax1Complete)
       {
          //make another ajax call here and onsuccess set ajax1Complete to false
       }
 });
```

Comment: i tried the code the pop is coming but the ajax is not running in the backend.

Comment: @user2728024 is it running if you remove `beforeSend`??

Comment: @user2728024 try removing `async:false` too once!!

Comment: sorry my mistake. I forgot the comma afte beforesend.

but when i added the comma it did not work

Comment: it worked when i removed async false. But i need that to be set since i my code has two ajax calls.

Comment: if you have 2 ajax calls then you can do it using `$.when` and `.done` right?

Comment: sorry for m ignorance i am new to php  could you please give the code for the same.

Comment: @user2728024 Updated answer. check and let me know!!

Comment: when i removed async the order of ajax is not corect even afte using .done()

Comment: Ok!! Now just tel me what is happening when you are using `$.when` and `.done`!! Loading is coming fine?? What else problem you see now!! because this is the proper way to do it when `async:false` is removed!!

Comment: the 2nd ajaxcall gets executed first

Comment: Am not sure buddy!! These are the best ways to use multiple ajax call!! Or else you need to revert back to `async:false` and remove `beforeSend` but seriously that's the bad practice in many cases!! and I guess since you are running it in the `localhost` you your requests gets executed fast and my not be able to see the loading image when you go with first approach!!

Comment: Anytime!! Happy coding!!